# IIS custom errors over domain trust

Tags: c#, iis, error-handling, asp-classic, runtime-error

We have recently implemented a two way domain trust between Company A and Company B.

A classic asp/asp.net application runs on a single instance of IIS6 (running on win server 2003) within Company A's domain. The application is configured to use Integrated Windows Authentication.

When testing from company B machine, the application can be accessed fine.

The issue that we have identified is with custom error pages configured in IIS.

---

For example:

Company B clicks on a link to '/non_existent_page.asp', it hangs for a bit and then we eventually receive a user/passwd prompt. We then receive the following error in event viewer

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID: 1000
Date: 13/08/2014
Time: 16:00:11
User: N/A
Description:
Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.3959, stamp 45d6968e, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.5295, stamp 52f3551e, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000bf93.
```

This temporarily makes the site unavailable for all users.

The user receives the following error in browser:

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the 
credentials that you supplied because your Web browser is sending a 
WWW-Authenticate header field that the Web server is not configured 
to accept.
```

---

When we enter the same URL directly into the browser's address bar, there is no issue and the custom 404 page is displayed.

The site has been added to the 'Local Intranet' trusted zone.

Broken links to aspx pages are handled by the web.config - so no problem there.

As a work around, we remove the custom 404 page in IIS and use the default file version found in `windows\help\iishelp\common` - This resolves the issue, but we'd really like to use our own page for these errors.

Any ideas on how we could resolve/debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to have a look at the Edit Custom Error Page under IIS.

IIS --> App --> ErrorPages --> Error Codes that you want to modify